# How do spreadsheet programs propagate changes?

Tags: excel, reactive-programming, spreadsheet

In an Excel like program, If cell A2 is (A1 + 5) and A3 is (A1 + A2), how would the changes in A1 be propagated to A2 and A3. If A2 is observing changes in A1, ad A3 is observing both, A2 and A3, how does the program ensure that changes first reflect in A2 and then in A3?

Comment: It will always calculate the precedents before calculating the formula.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a dataflow algorithm that makes sure that all newly calculated cells get broadcast amongst all cells, and dependent cells (i.e. the cells that uses cell operands) fetch the broadcast value and update it. This means all operands must be calculated first and then the cell that uses the values.

Comment: Here's a write up on the [Excel Calculation Order](http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm). I can't vouch for its accuracy, but it seems to match other things I've understood along the way.

Comment: Thanks @PeterT . I should have been ready going into that article with the simplistic model in my mind :-) .

Comment: I think they use topological sorting to arrange the dependencies like in which order the updates are "propagated". https://secweb.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cs361/web/website/Lectures/graphalgorithms/pages/ar01s01s02.html